# Could not initialize class org.hibernate.boot.registry.classloading.internal.ClassLoaderServiceImpl

Tags: hibernate, maven, intellij-idea, javafx

I have created a maven javafx and use hibernate yo connect mysql db.
my pom.xml:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>Hibernate2</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>Hibernate2</name>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <junit.version>5.8.1</junit.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
            <artifactId>javafx-controls</artifactId>
            <version>11.0.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
            <artifactId>javafx-fxml</artifactId>
            <version>11.0.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-jupiter-api</artifactId>
            <version>${junit.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-jupiter-engine</artifactId>
            <version>${junit.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
            <version>5.3.15.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <version>8.0.15</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.8.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>11</source>
                    <target>11</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
                <artifactId>javafx-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>0.0.8</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <!-- Default configuration for running with: mvn clean javafx:run -->
                        <id>default-cli</id>
                        <configuration>
                            <mainClass>com.example.hibernate2/com.example.hibernate2.HelloApplication</mainClass>
                            <launcher>app</launcher>
                            <jlinkZipName>app</jlinkZipName>
                            <jlinkImageName>app</jlinkImageName>
                            <noManPages>true</noManPages>
                            <stripDebug>true</stripDebug>
                            <noHeaderFiles>true</noHeaderFiles>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

HibernateUtil.class:

```
    package com.example.hibernate2;

import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.hibernate.boot.Metadata;
import org.hibernate.boot.MetadataSources;
import org.hibernate.boot.registry.StandardServiceRegistry;
import org.hibernate.boot.registry.StandardServiceRegistryBuilder;

public class HibernateUtil {
    private static StandardServiceRegistry registry;
    private static SessionFactory sessionFactory;

    public static SessionFactory getSessionFactory() {
        if (sessionFactory == null) {
            try {
                // Create registry
                registry = new StandardServiceRegistryBuilder().configure().build();

                // Create MetadataSources
                MetadataSources sources = new MetadataSources(registry);

                // Create Metadata
                Metadata metadata = sources.getMetadataBuilder().build();

                // Create SessionFactory
                sessionFactory = metadata.getSessionFactoryBuilder().build();

            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                if (registry != null) {
                    StandardServiceRegistryBuilder.destroy(registry);
                }
            }
        }
        return sessionFactory;
    }

    public static void shutdown() {
        if (registry != null) {
            StandardServiceRegistryBuilder.destroy(registry);
        }
    }

}
```

hibernate.cfg.xml

```
?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
        <!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC
                "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD//EN"
                "http://hibernate.org/hibernate-configuration-5.0.dtd">
<hibernate-configuration>
    <session-factory>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.url">mysql://127.0.0.1:3306/xxxx</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.username">root</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.password">xxxxx</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.pool_size">10</property>
        <property name="show_sql">true</property>
        <property name="dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</property>
        <property name="hibernate.current_session_context_class">thread</property>


        <mapping class="com.example.hibernate2.Utenti"></mapping>


    </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

Utenti.class

```
package com.example.hibernate2;

import javax.persistence.*;

@Entity
@Table(name = "Utenti")
public class Utenti {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id_utente", nullable = false)
    private Integer id;

    @Column(name = "email", length = 45)
    private String email;

    @Column(name = "utente", length = 45)
    private String utente;

    @Column(name = "password", length = 45)
    private String password;

    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }

    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }

    public String getUtente() {
        return utente;
    }

    public void setUtente(String utente) {
        this.utente = utente;
    }

    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }

    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }

    public Integer getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Integer id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
```

module-info:

```
module com.example.hibernate2 {
    requires javafx.controls;
    requires javafx.fxml;
    requires java.persistence;
    requires org.hibernate.orm.core;
    requires java.naming;


    opens com.example.hibernate2 to javafx.fxml;
    exports com.example.hibernate2;
}
```

This is error:

> Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread"
> java.lang.RuntimeException:
> java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException   at
> javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$MethodHandler.invoke(FXMLLoader.java:1787)
> at
> javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$ControllerMethodEventHandler.handle(FXMLLoader.java:1670)
> at
> javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:86)
> at
> javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:238)
> at
> javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:191)
> at
> javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventDispatcher.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventDispatcher.java:59)
> at
> javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:58)
> at
> javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
> at
> javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
> at
> javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
> at
> javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
> at
> javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
> at
> javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEventImpl(EventUtil.java:74)
> at
> javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEvent(EventUtil.java:49)
> at javafx.base/javafx.event.Event.fireEvent(Event.java:198)     at
> javafx.graphics/javafx.scene.Node.fireEvent(Node.java:8879)   at
> javafx.controls/javafx.scene.control.Button.fire(Button.java:200)     at
> javafx.controls/com.sun.javafx.scene.control.behavior.ButtonBehavior.mouseReleased(ButtonBehavior.java:206)
> at
> javafx.controls/com.sun.javafx.scene.control.inputmap.InputMap.handle(InputMap.java:274)
> at
> javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler$NormalEventHandlerRecord.handleBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:218)
> at
> javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:80)
> at
> javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:238)
> at
> javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:191)
> at
> javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventDispatcher.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventDispatcher.java:59)
> at
> javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:58)
> at
> javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
> at
> javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
> at
> javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
> at
> javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
> at
> javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
> at
> javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEventImpl(EventUtil.java:74)
> at
> javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEvent(EventUtil.java:54)
> at javafx.base/javafx.event.Event.fireEvent(Event.java:198)     at
> javafx.graphics/javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.process(Scene.java:3851)
> at
> javafx.graphics/javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.access$1200(Scene.java:3579)
> at
> javafx.graphics/javafx.scene.Scene.processMouseEvent(Scene.java:1849)
> at
> javafx.graphics/javafx.scene.Scene$ScenePeerListener.mouseEvent(Scene.java:2588)
> at
> javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$MouseEventNotification.run(GlassViewEventHandler.java:397)
> at
> javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$MouseEventNotification.run(GlassViewEventHandler.java:295)
> at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native
> Method)   at
> javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.lambda$handleMouseEvent$2(GlassViewEventHandler.java:434)
> at
> javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.runWithoutRenderLock(QuantumToolkit.java:390)
> at
> javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.handleMouseEvent(GlassViewEventHandler.java:433)
> at
> javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.View.handleMouseEvent(View.java:556)
> at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.View.notifyMouse(View.java:942)
> at
> javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.mac.MacView.notifyMouse(MacView.java:127)
> Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException    at
> java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native
> Method)   at
> java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
> at
> java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
> at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)   at
> com.sun.javafx.reflect.Trampoline.invoke(MethodUtil.java:76)  at
> java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native
> Method)   at
> java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
> at
> java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
> at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)   at
> javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.reflect.MethodUtil.invoke(MethodUtil.java:273)
> at
> javafx.fxml/com.sun.javafx.fxml.MethodHelper.invoke(MethodHelper.java:83)
> at
> javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$MethodHandler.invoke(FXMLLoader.java:1784)
> ... 45 more Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not
> initialize class
> org.hibernate.boot.registry.classloading.internal.ClassLoaderServiceImpl
> at
> org.hibernate.orm.core@5.3.15.Final/org.hibernate.boot.registry.BootstrapServiceRegistryBuilder.build(BootstrapServiceRegistryBuilder.java:218)
> at
> org.hibernate.orm.core@5.3.15.Final/org.hibernate.boot.registry.StandardServiceRegistryBuilder.(StandardServiceRegistryBuilder.java:87)
> at
> com.example.hibernate2/com.example.hibernate2.HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory(HibernateUtil.java:17)
> at
> com.example.hibernate2/com.example.hibernate2.HelloController.onHelloButtonClick(HelloController.java:15)
> ... 57 more

Comment: Edit the question.  Format the stack trace as code.

Comment: If you have a module-info, remove or fix it.

Answer (score 0):

I tried creating a running example from your code.  I couldn't produce your exact error, but I did get something to run. It required these fixes:

1. Change JavaFX version to 19 (the 11 version you have displays corrupted text on MacOS).
2. Change package and module name to `com.example.dbaccess`, otherwise my IDE warns me that the module name should not end in a number.
3. Add `requires java.sql;`, otherwise, the SQL module is not visible and a session cannot be created.
4. Use h2 rather than MySQL.  MySQL will probably work, but I didn't want to install it.
5. Open your module to `org.hibernate.orm.core`, otherwise hibernate can't use reflection on the entity class (which it needs to do).
6. Add missing code for the application, controller and fxml.

*Sample code*

To use, copy the code, build and run it, pressing the button to establish a hibernate session.  I used OpenJDK 19.0.2 to compile and run the code via Idea.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>Hibernate2</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>Hibernate2</name>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <junit.version>5.8.1</junit.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
            <artifactId>javafx-controls</artifactId>
            <version>19</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
            <artifactId>javafx-fxml</artifactId>
            <version>19</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
            <version>5.3.20.Final</version>
        </dependency>
<!--        <dependency>-->
<!--            <groupId>mysql</groupId>-->
<!--            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>-->
<!--            <version>8.0.28</version>-->
<!--        </dependency>-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
            <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.214</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.8.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>11</source>
                    <target>11</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

---

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
        <!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC
                "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD//EN"
                "http://hibernate.org/hibernate-configuration-5.0.dtd">
<hibernate-configuration>
    <session-factory>
<!--        <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver</property>-->
<!--        <property name="hibernate.connection.url">mysql://127.0.0.1:3306/xxxx</property>-->
<!--        <property name="hibernate.connection.username">root</property>-->
<!--        <property name="hibernate.connection.password">xxxxx</property>-->
<!--        <property name="hibernate.connection.pool_size">10</property>-->
        <property name="show_sql">true</property>
<!--        <property name="dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</property>-->

        <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">org.h2.Driver</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:h2:mem:testdb</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.username">sa</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.password">password</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.pool_size">10</property>
        <property name="dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect</property>
        <property name="hibernate.current_session_context_class">thread</property>

        <mapping class="com.example.dbaccess.Utenti"/>
    </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

---

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.geometry.Insets?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Label?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.VBox?>

<?import javafx.scene.control.Button?>
<VBox alignment="CENTER" spacing="20.0" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml"
      fx:controller="com.example.dbaccess.HelloController">
    <padding>
        <Insets bottom="20.0" left="20.0" right="20.0" top="20.0"/>
    </padding>

    <Label fx:id="welcomeText"/>
    <Button text="Hello!" onAction="#onHelloButtonClick"/>
</VBox>
```

---

```
module com.example.dbaccess {
    requires javafx.controls;
    requires javafx.fxml;
    requires org.hibernate.orm.core;
    requires java.persistence;
    requires java.sql;

    opens com.example.dbaccess to javafx.fxml, org.hibernate.orm.core;
    exports com.example.dbaccess;
}
```

---

```
package com.example.dbaccess;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

import java.io.IOException;

public class HelloApplication extends Application {
    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) throws IOException {
        FXMLLoader fxmlLoader = new FXMLLoader(HelloApplication.class.getResource("hello-view.fxml"));
        Scene scene = new Scene(fxmlLoader.load(), 320, 240);
        stage.setTitle("Hello!");
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch();
    }
}
```

---

```
package com.example.dbaccess;

import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;

public class HelloController {
    @FXML
    private Label welcomeText;

    @FXML
    protected void onHelloButtonClick() {
        SessionFactory sessionFactory = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory();
    }
}
```

---

```
package com.example.dbaccess;

import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.hibernate.boot.Metadata;
import org.hibernate.boot.MetadataSources;
import org.hibernate.boot.registry.StandardServiceRegistry;
import org.hibernate.boot.registry.StandardServiceRegistryBuilder;

public class HibernateUtil {
    private static StandardServiceRegistry registry;
    private static SessionFactory sessionFactory;

    public static SessionFactory getSessionFactory() {
        if (sessionFactory == null) {
            try {
                // Create registry
                registry = new StandardServiceRegistryBuilder().configure().build();

                // Create MetadataSources
                MetadataSources sources = new MetadataSources(registry);

                // Create Metadata
                Metadata metadata = sources.getMetadataBuilder().build();

                // Create SessionFactory
                sessionFactory = metadata.getSessionFactoryBuilder().build();

            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                if (registry != null) {
                    StandardServiceRegistryBuilder.destroy(registry);
                }
            }
        }
        return sessionFactory;
    }

    public static void shutdown() {
        if (registry != null) {
            StandardServiceRegistryBuilder.destroy(registry);
        }
    }

}
```

---

```
package com.example.dbaccess;

import javax.persistence.*;

@Entity
@Table(name = "Utenti")
public class Utenti {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id_utente", nullable = false)
    private Integer id;

    @Column(name = "email", length = 45)
    private String email;

    @Column(name = "utente", length = 45)
    private String utente;

    @Column(name = "password", length = 45)
    private String password;

    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }

    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }

    public String getUtente() {
        return utente;
    }

    public void setUtente(String utente) {
        this.utente = utente;
    }

    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }

    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }

    public Integer getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Integer id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
}
```

*Execution output*

```
Feb 13, 2023 11:09:33 AM org.hibernate.Version logVersion
INFO: HHH000412: Hibernate Core {[WORKING]}
Feb 13, 2023 11:09:33 AM org.hibernate.cfg.Environment <clinit>
INFO: HHH000206: hibernate.properties not found
Feb 13, 2023 11:09:33 AM org.hibernate.annotations.common.reflection.java.JavaReflectionManager <clinit>
INFO: HCANN000001: Hibernate Commons Annotations {5.0.4.Final}
Feb 13, 2023 11:09:33 AM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl configure
WARN: HHH10001002: Using Hibernate built-in connection pool (not for production use!)
Feb 13, 2023 11:09:33 AM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl buildCreator
INFO: HHH10001005: using driver [org.h2.Driver] at URL [jdbc:h2:mem:testdb]
Feb 13, 2023 11:09:33 AM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl buildCreator
INFO: HHH10001001: Connection properties: {password=****, user=sa}
Feb 13, 2023 11:09:33 AM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl buildCreator
INFO: HHH10001003: Autocommit mode: false
Feb 13, 2023 11:09:33 AM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl$PooledConnections <init>
INFO: HHH000115: Hibernate connection pool size: 10 (min=1)
Feb 13, 2023 11:09:33 AM org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect <init>
INFO: HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect
```